# Visual assistent doesn't show

Tags: android, layout, window, upgrade

I have a problem since the upgrade of Android studio.
When i try to use a layout it works but when i slide an item on the screen (window design) to see how it's looks like, the item didn't appeared in the window design, just in the window text.
Maybe i need to choose a parameter but i cannot find it.

[image]

If you don't know how to fix this, maybe you can explain me how back in the last version
Thanks for help.

Comment: try clicking the two stacked blue layers above the layout view and then click force refresh layout

Comment: It doesn't work...